# If data fits on a single machine does it make sense to use Spark?

Tags: scala, parallel-processing, apache-spark

I have 20GB of data that requires processing, all of this data fits on my local machine. I'm planning on using Spark or Scala parallel colleections to implement some algorithms and matrix multiplication against this data.

Since the data fits on a single machine should I use Scala parallel collections ?

Is this true : The main bottleneck in parallel tasks is getting the data to the CPU for processing,  so since all of the data is as close as can be to the CPU Spark will not give any significant performance improvement ?

Spark will have the overhead setting up parallel tasks even though it will be just running on one machine, so this overhead is redundant in this case ?

Comment: *all of this data fits on my local machine* Are you talking about RAM?

Comment: @om-nom-nom yes im talking about RAM

Comment: sorry for repeating the question: When you say "I've 20GB of data" and "fits in my local machine". Is the 20GB a file and the assumption is that you have more than 20GB of RAM? Or is 20GB of data measured when it's already loaded in RAM?

Comment: @maasg I'm basing the 20GB measurement on 20GB is a file and I have  more than 20GB of RAM?"

Comment: 20GB of data might become much more on RAM as objects and data structures have an overhead space cost. Also operations on RDD's will create new RDD's, multiplying that memory cost factor. It's hard to exactly quantify in a generic way but you will need many times the size of your data in RAM in order to process it. All depending on the depth and complexity of your analytics pipeline.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's hard to provide some non-obvious instructions, like *if you had your data and  doesn't goes up to the 80% of memory and ..., then use local mode*. Having said this, there are couple of points, which, in general, may make you use spark even if your data fits one's machine memory:

1. really intensive CPU processing, from the top of my head, it might be complicated parsing of texts
2. stability -- say you have many processing stages and you don't want to lose results, once your single machine goes down.
   it's especially important in case you have recurrent calculations, not one-off queries (this way, time you spend on bringing spark to the table might pay-off)
3. streaming -- you get your data from somewhere in a stream manner, and, though it's snapshot fits single machine, you have to orchestrate it somehow

In your particular case

> so since all of the data is as close as can be to the CPU Spark will
>   not give any significant performance improvement

Of course it's not, Spark is not a voodoo magic that somehow might get your data closer to the CPU, but it can help you scale among machines, thus CPUs (point #1)

> Spark will have the overhead setting up parallel tasks even though it
>   will be just running on one machine, so this overhead is redundant in
>   this case ?

I may sound captain obvious, but

1. Take #2 and #3 into consideration, do you need them? If yes, go spark or something else
2. If no, implement your processing in a dumb way (parallel collections)
3. Profile and take a look. Are your processing is CPU bound? Can you speed up it, without lot of tweaks? If no, go spark.

There is also [cheeky] point 4) in the list of *Why should I use Spark?*. It's the hype -- Spark is a very sexy technology which is easy to "sell" to both your devs (it's the cutting edge of big data) and the company (your boss, in case you're building your own product, your customer in case you're building product for somebody else).

Comment: For point #1, doesn't the fact that spark can exploit multiple threads mean *it can* give a performance improvement for multi-threaded cpus?

Comment: @anthonybell I think parallel collections will perform much more efficiently in this circumstances